При выполнении кода через Access пишет, что пропущен символ ; в конце кода
Код выглядит так, проблема только с Values 2 и 3, если вставлять только Values 1, то код запускается.
Код выглядит так, проблема только с Values 2 и 3, если вставлять только Values 1, то код запускается
INSERT INTO
Экскурсия ([код экскурсии], название, описание, цена)

VALUES (1, '[Экскурсия
«Ледниковый период»]', '[В ходе экскурсии «Ледниковый период: время больших
холодов и больших зверей» вы узнаете, кто населял территорию современной
Тульской области во времена Ледниковых периодов.]', 300)

VALUES (2, '[Экскурсия
по Тульскому областному краеведческому музею]', '[На экскурсии в Тульском
областном краеведческом музее посетители познакомятся с богатой историей
тульского края]', 300)

VALUES (3, '[Тематическая
экскурсия «Прикоснись к истории»]', '[В Тульском областном краеведческом музее
можно не только познакомиться с историей родного края, но и прикоснуться к ней
в буквальном смысле!]', 300)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Если правильно помню, иструкции values должны быть разделены запятыми.

-- Создание таблицы Экскурсия
CREATE TABLE Экскурсия
(
    кодЭкскурсии SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    название VARCHAR(100),
    описание VARCHAR(300),
    цена SERIAL
);

-- Добавление новых записей в таблицу Экскурсия
INSERT INTO
Экскурсия (кодЭкскурсии, название, описание, цена)

VALUES (1, '[Экскурсия «Ледниковый период»]', '[В ходе экскурсии «Ледниковый период: время больших
холодов и больших зверей» вы узнаете, кто населял территорию современной
Тульской области во времена Ледниковых периодов.]', 300),

(2, '[Экскурсия по Тульскому областному краеведческому музею]', '[На экскурсии в Тульском
областном краеведческом музее посетители познакомятся с богатой историей
тульского края', 300),

(3, '[Тематическая экскурсия «Прикоснись к истории»]', '[В Тульском областном краеведческом музее
можно не только познакомиться с историей родного края, но и прикоснуться к ней
в буквальном смысле!', 300);

-- Вывод таблицы
SELECT *
FROM Экскурсия;

